# make .combine function scaleable

Tags: r, foreach, domc

I am trying to use foreach and am having problems making the .combine function scalable.  For example, here is a simple combine function

```
MyComb <- function(part1,part2){
          xs <- c(part1$x,part2$x)
          ys <- c(part1$y,part2$y)
          return(list(xs,ys))
          }
```

When I use this function to combine a foreach statement with an iterator other than 2 it returns it incorrectly.  For example this works:

```
   x = foreach(i=1:2,.combine=MyComb) %dopar% list("x"=i*2,"y"=i*3)
```

But not this:

```
 x = foreach(i=1:3,.combine=MyComb) %dopar% list("x"=i*2,"y"=i*3)
```

Is there a way to generalize the combine function to make it scalable to n iterations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.combine` function must take either two pieces and return something that "looks" like a piece (could be passed back in as a part) or take many arguments and put all of them together at once (with the same restrictions).  Thus at least your `MyComb` must return a list with components `x` and `y` (which is what each piece of your `%dopar%` do.

A couple of ways to do this:

```
MyComb1 <- function(part1, part2) {
    list(x=c(part1$x, part2$x), y=c(part1$y, part2$y))
}

x = foreach(i=1:3,.combine=MyComb1) %dopar% list("x"=i*2,"y"=i*3)
```

This version takes only two pieces at a time.

```
MyComb2 <- function(...) {
    dots = list(...)
    ret <- lapply(names(dots[[1]]), function(e) {
        unlist(sapply(dots, '[[', e))
    })
    names(ret) <- names(dots[[1]])
    ret
}

s = foreach(i=1:3,.combine=MyComb2) %dopar% list("x"=i*2,"y"=i*3)
x = foreach(i=1:3,.combine=MyComb2, .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% list("x"=i*2,"y"=i*3)
```

This one can take multiple pieces at a time and combine them.  It is more general (but more complex).

Comment: Thanks!  So in my actual application each bit supplied to MyComb is a list with a bunch of elements each being matrix.  I want to abind(...,along=3) each matrix of the same name from the original list and finally return a big list with these arrays.  I am having trouble seeing how to do that with your MyComb2 solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: @scottyaz Probably just replace `unlist(...)` with `abind(...,along=3)`, but without building a working example, I am not sure.  The result of `sapply(dots, '[[', e)` is a list of the components with the name "e" from every part.  `abind` can take a list as its argument, so it should work with what is returned from the `sapply`.